# SQL Server will not work after windows update

Tags: sql-server, windows

My Windows 10 machine insists on doing an update every so often after which MSSQL Server will not start. When I try and start it manually from services I get the following error:

> Windows could not start the SQL Server () service on Local Computer. Error 2: The System cannot find the file specified

The only way to rectify it is to undo the last update from the updates panel in windows. But every couple of days I come back to it and the update has executed again. Any ideas on how to trouble shoot the above error?

Comment: This is  strange, can you share your windows version and type of updates due to which this happens

Comment: What does SQL error log and eventvwr say ?